# Javascript library to split and merge PDF?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, documentum

Is there a good javascript library to manipulate PDF files "visually" ?

I'm looking for something that allow me to view a PDF page by page into one container, and drag and drop page by page to a new empty container to make the new PDF and then I could save all modification in my docbase. 
I did some searches and didn't find something that do that, except some heavy clients, but I want to integrate this functionnality into my webapp...

Also thought about some custom dev, but can't really estimate the time it would take...

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Your best bet is something like https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF but it would take some work to build a visual drag-and-drop on top of that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll go with a custom JS / html5 dev for the visual drag-and-drop and when launch the process i'll do the split and merge via iText.

Comment: Sounds great!  If you do finish it and it's a public site, please post it here so we can see what you did.  Or maybe blog about it.